# Loads different image folder by window width

Tags: jquery, if-statement, responsive-design

I`m making a responsive site, but I need to load different images for different screen sizes.
I tried to set a value to a variable 'path' depending the window.width, getting the image name by a class applied on the image.

Why doesn't it function?

```
 if (window.width() <= 410) {
     var path = 'images/small/';
 } else 
 if (window.width() <= 650) {
var path = 'images/medium/';
 } else {
   var path = 'images/big/';
 }

 $('.gallery li').click(function(){
    $('.content').load(path + $(this).attr('class'));
    });
 });
```

Comment: What not using CSS Media Queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can't load images using jQuery.load method. You should put image tag:

```
$('.gallery li').click(function(){
    var img = $("<img />");
    img.attr('src', path + $(this).attr('class'));
    $('.content').replaceWith(img);
});
```

In addition, it will be much better idea to use data attribute instead of class to get image names. For example:

```
<ul class="gallery"><li data-image="example.jpg"> ... </li> ... </ul>
```

Comment: A great example, and without usage of plugins! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a responsive website, your best friends are CSS Media Queries. Head over to [Media Queries](http://mediaqueri.es) to see some examples.

If you want to use a JavaScript and jQuery, I'd suggest to use a jQuery plugin instead of creating your own. [Here's an example](http://jquerypicture.com/).

Also, for CSS, there are frameworks too. From the creator of the above plugin, [here's one for CSS](http://responsablecss.com/).

Comment: I used media queries for other browsers, but i like so much of respond.js and this plugin you showed.